# UITableView autoresizing masks on by default?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have some tableviews in my application and I have set the autoresizing masks to flexible width and height. However when I opened a viewcontroller where I use a tableView I noticed that I had not set the autoresizing masks, however the tableview looks resizes correctly on iPad. Does it mean that setting autoresizing masks on tableview is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, the UIViewController framework likes to explicitly resize its views depending on the context in which they're presented.  For example, on iPhone UINavigationController and UITabBarController explicitly resize the views of their viewControllers to fill all available screen real estate.  On iPad, UISplitViewController explicitly resizes the views of its master and detail view controllers to fit their appropriate dimensions in landscape mode.  This explicit resizing performed by these container view controllers is not technically autoresizing, so these view controllers disregard the view's autoresizingMask.

A view's autoresizingMask answers one specific question: How should this view behave if the bounds of its superview change?  When a UIViewController's view gets explicitly resized by a container view controller, this is not considered autoresizing because it's not happening as a result of a change in the superview's bounds.

Of course if the explicitly resized view has subviews, those subviews will get autoresized  as a side-effect of the explicit resizing of their superview, as specified by their autoresizingMasks (provided that the superview has autoresizesSubviews set to YES).

Answer (score 0):

yes. when you added tableview in .xib then its default property is flexible width and height.

Comment: then yup its a default property. May be it happens in new sdk.